# can i use google maps data for my own app on android?

Tags: database, android, api, google-maps

i want to know if i can use the data (for exaple a tour from point A to point B) and extract it for example to save the tour infos to an text file or post it somewhere or do whatever i want with it? i want to use maps as a database, so what are the restrictions, what am i allowed to do?

Comment: please elaborate your question. what do you want? exactly..

Comment: i want to use the tour data you can create in google maps in my own app by using the maps api but not displaying it on the map. google maps has this great big database and can do all the tour calculations for me but i dont want to display it on the screen necessary.

Comment: @Sponge Can u Give me some Information Regarding Goole Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice, but my reading of the [terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) is:

According to [section 10.12](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12), you are not allowed to show the "Content" except in conjunction with a Google map.  I'm pretty sure the route information would be considered content, so you wouldn't be able to post it somewhere else unless you show a Google map with it.

You are allowed to "temporarily" store the "Content" in your database, if it is for the purpose of later showing in conjunction with a Google map ([section 10.3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_3)).